# Create an unique integer id column for an existing string column

Tags: postgresql, computed-column, unique-constraint

I have an PostgreSQL server with an existing table which has an fixed-width-non-unique-string column such as this:

```
| ID_STRING |
| 'ABCDEFG' |
| 'HIJKLMN' |
```

Now I want to compute integer ids for each element and store them into an additional column. The result should look like this:

```
| ID_STRING | ID_INT
| 'ABCDEFG' |   1
| 'HIJKLMN' |   2
| 'ABCDEFG' |   1
| 'HIJKLMN' |   2
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: That value isn't unique.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: the value itself inside the column should not be unique. May ID_INT is better explained as integer representation of ID_STRING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add the new column use:

```
ALTER TABLE the_table ADD COLUMN id_int integer;
```

To populate the new column you need an UPDATE statement.

I am assuming you have a primary key column named `pk_column` in your table. Obviously you need to replace that with the *actual* primary key column in your table.

```
update the_table
   set id_int = t.rn
from (
  select pk_column, 
         dense_rank() over (order by id_string) as rn
  from the_table
) t
where the_table.pk_column = t.pk_column;
```

---

If you really have a table without a primary key (why?), you can use the built-in `ctid` instead:

```
update the_table
   set id_int = t.rn
from (
  select ctid as id_, 
         dense_rank() over (order by id_string) as rn
  from the_table
) t
where the_table.ctid = t.id_;
```

Comment: There is no primary key inside of this column.

Comment: @nali: you mean you have a table without a primary key? That is a really bad idea. How do you update a single row in that table?

Comment: Is it necessary for static databases where no rows will be altered?

Comment: @nali: how do you retrieve a single row without a unique key?

Comment: There is an geometry column which I fetch with boundingboxes.

Comment: Your update script seems to work but the sourceode itselft takes a while. Which complexity is it? this table has has serveral million data-rows.

Comment: Of course that will run a while it will update **all** rows and and it needs to **sort** all rows in order to do the counting.

Comment: It surprises me because the select part is done within seconds while the update itself is 10minutes. Is there a way to accelerate it? Something like creating the column somewhere else and moving into the table?

Comment: @nali: then it's the update that is slow, plus the comparison on `ctid` is known to be slow as well.

Comment: Would it lower the 10 minutes update if I had an integer primary key inside this column?

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is a little difficult to understand. It seems you want a unique ID value per unique string value, but not unique across the entire data set, i.e. if you have ABCDEF multiple times in the data set, the integer value will be the same across them.

If so, you can use the [DENSE_RANK()](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-dense_rank-function/) function to produce an incrementing integer id grouped based on the non-unique strings. Example below:

```
CREATE TABLE DataTable (NonUniqueString VARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO DataTable
VALUES ('ABCDEF'), ('GHIJKL'), ('ABCDEF'), ('GHIJKL'), ('ABCDEF')

SELECT NonUniqueString,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY NonUniqueString) AS "Group"
FROM DataTable
```

Results:

```
NonUniqueString     Group
-------------------------
ABCDEF              1
ABCDEF              1
ABCDEF              1
GHIJKL              2
GHIJKL              2
```

NOTE: The example was from MS SQL Server but the DENSE_RANK() function should behave the same in PostgreSQL and uses the same syntax.

Comment: It looks good and creates the ID's I've expected. But how to add the additional column into the same database? I've  tried ALTER TABLE mytbl ADD COLUMN id_num INTEGER;
INSERT INTO mytbl ( id_num ) 
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id_string ) id_num FROM tracks;