# How to install pgcrypto?

Tags: postgresql, linux

While trying to answer [Create integer id columns from existing string columns (integer coding?)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242888/create-integer-id-columns-from-existing-string-columns-integer-coding/242892?noredirect=1#comment479424_242892) it turned out that I needed my own version of postgres to play with. I already had a decent postgres version installed:

```
stack=# select version();
                                                version                         

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 9.1.1 20190503 (R
ed Hat 9.1.1-1), 64-bit
```

but it did not have the pgcrypto module:

```
stack=# CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-11/share/extension/pgcrypto.control": No such file or directory
```

so I installed:

```
sudo dnf install postgresql-contrib
```

but I still get the same error. If I look in:

```
]$ ls /usr/pgsql-11/share/extension/
plpgsql--1.0.sql  plpgsql.control  plpgsql--unpackaged--1.0.sql
```

Is there any other package I need to install, or am I missing something else?

UPDATE:

```
rpm -qa postgresql\* 
postgresql-contrib-11.3-1.fc30.x86_64 
postgresql11-11.4-1PGDG.f30.x86_64 
postgresql-11.3-1.fc30.x86_64 
postgresql11-server-11.4-1PGDG.f30.x86_64 
postgresql11-libs-11.4-1PGDG.f30.x86_64
```

I get an error for dnf install postgresql11-contrib:

[...]
   Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'fedora-modular'
   Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'fedora-modular'

pdgd seems to be the latest availible:

```
rpm -qa | grep pgdg-fedora
pgdg-fedora-repo-42.0-4.noarch
```

UPDATE2:

Apparently something where temporarily down, it now worked to:

```
sudo dnf install postgresql11-contrib
[...]
Downloading Packages:
postgresql11-contrib-11.4-1PGDG.f30.x86_64.rpm  285 kB/s | 602 kB     00:02    

rpm -qa postgresql\*
postgresql-contrib-11.3-1.fc30.x86_64
postgresql11-11.4-1PGDG.f30.x86_64
postgresql11-contrib-11.4-1PGDG.f30.x86_64
postgresql-11.3-1.fc30.x86_64
postgresql11-server-11.4-1PGDG.f30.x86_64
postgresql11-libs-11.4-1PGDG.f30.x86_64

stack=# CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`contrib` is correct, but you must have installed it for a different PostgreSQL than the one you are using.

Find out which packages are installed:

```
rpm -qa postgresql\*
```

Odds are that you need to run

```
dnf install postgresql11-contrib
```

Comment: Thanks, retried to install postgresql11-contrib and now it worked